# Wpf Style is only applied in the editor view

Tags: wpf, xaml

As I wanted to define a default text style for a Textblock, I created a ResourceDictionary

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontLight}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

which is referenced in the `App.xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFontLight"> path to font </FontFamily>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In the editor view, the style is applied properly, but when I run the application in debug/release mode, is uses some other default font style and not the one I specified.

**EDIT:** I found out, that the problem is `StaticResource DefaultFontLight`, which seems not to be found in the `ResourceDictionary` `Styles.xaml` even though this Resource exists. If I replace the StaticResource with the actual path, everything works. Also, if I copy the style in the `App.xaml` it works too

```
<Application.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFontLight"> path to font </FontFamily>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontLight}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/Styles.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least point out where you expect the style to get applied?

Comment: As I did not specify x:Key, the style should be applied to all TextBlocks  in that application according to [Implicit Styles](https://michaelscodingspot.com/explicit-implicit-and-default-styles-in-wpf/).

Comment: Only if said TextBlock is **NOT** in a `DataTemplate`.